# Как правильно рассчитать итоговую стоимость?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Делаю калькулятор для сайта. Для вывода итоговой стоимости использую функцию:

```
function updatePrice() {
    let kraskaPrice = currentSet.getKraskaPrice();
    let dopPrice = currentSet.getDopPrice();
    let selsgPrice = currentSet.getSelsgPrice();
    let selspPrice = currentSet.getSelspPrice();
    let sellgPrice = currentSet.getSellgPrice();
    let sellpPrice = currentSet.getSellpPrice();
    let totalPrice = (currentSet.dlina + currentSet.kolichestvo) * (kraskaPrice + dopPrice + lastPrice);
    total.value = totalPrice;
}
```

Мне необходимо сумму переменных (currentSet.dlina и currentSet.kolichestvo) перемножить с переменными (kraskaPrice, dopPrice, lastPrice), но, к сожалению, мой способ со скобками не работает.
Мой код: https://codepen.io/till728/pen/LYryJbB

Comment: Где объявление переменной **lastPrice**? И переменные **let sel(*)** не используются в коде

Comment: странно даже, что у вас функция названа `updatePrice` а не `obnovitPrice`

Answer (score 0):

дело не в скобках, проблема в том, что `currentSet.dlina` и `currentSet.kolichestvo` это строки а не числа. При получение данных из инпута - получается строка

Вам нужно эти переменные привести к числу, можно так:

`Number(currentSet.dlina)`

или так

`+currentSet.dlina`